# jQuery SlideDown with dynamically fixed center

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position, slidedown

I'm writing my own popUp function in jQuery. I get the width and height dynamically and then slide down the element after a click event.

But unfortunately after I wrote the part that determines the height and with and sets the center css, the slideDown function now makes the element appear in the center of the page and grow in the up and down direction simultaneously, instead just folding it down from the top.

The main source of the problem should be the `margin-top`, I guess.

Do you know how to fix this?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="Portfolio">
    <div id="PortfolioGrid">
        <div class="overlay">overlay</div>
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="close" style="display: none;">
                <i class="icn-x"></i>
            </div>
            <dl class="beschreibung">
                <dt>Beschreibung</dt>
                <dd>xsssxxsxsxsxssxsxsx</dd>
                <dt>Aufgabe</dt>
                <dd>dsfgfdgfgdf</dd>
                <dt>Kunde</dt>
                <dd>Bla</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 250px;
}

.popup {
    display: none;
}
.popup.clone {
    display: none;
    z-index: 5002;
    position: fixed;     
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.beschreibung {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#Portfolio").on("click", ".overlay", function() {
            var popup_state_port = false;
            if(popup_state_port == false) {

                var klon = $(this).nextAll('.popup').clone();
                $(klon).addClass('clone');
                $('#PortfolioGrid').after(klon);
                var width = $('.container').width();
                var height = $('.clone').height();
                //console.log(width);
                $('.clone').css({
                    'width': width,
                    'margin-left': -width/2,
                    'margin-top': -height/2
                })
                $('.clone').slideDown("normal", function() {
                    $(this).find('.close').fadeIn();
                });
                $(".bg").css("opacity", "0.7");
                $(".bg").fadeIn("normal");

                popup_state_port = true;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

and a FIDDLE, so that you can see the effect: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/27dBE/)**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
Ok, hopefully this is solution is usable for you. I centered the div vertically with only using `top`. It is possible to calculate a percentage and pixels in CSS with `calc()`
As far as I know you need prefixes to support all browsers:

```
$('.clone').css({
    'width': width,
    'margin-left': -width/2,
    'top': '-moz-calc(50% - '+height/2+'px)',
    'top': '-webkit-calc(50% - '+height/2+'px)',
    'top': '-o-calc(50% - '+height/2+'px)',
    'top': 'calc(50% - '+height/2+'px)'
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/27dBE/23/

Comment: Because I want to center the fixed div, therefore I need it. It might look like it works in the fiddle, but it doesn't in the project context. Read here about the needed css: http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Comment: Yes, this seems to work!! Thank you very much. I gotta read into `calc()`.. :)